# How to bind a model to an armature?

Tags: rigging, armature, vertex-groups

My pose mode simply does not move the body, I tried weight painting and everything but it just  does not move. It's a simple creation, just a body made simple...

I looked at some other people is works and all, all it seems to do is press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> *> Automatic Weights* but it does not move the body still.

Something I noticed is when I use *Automatic Weights* it creates many Vertex Groups called `Bone.XXX`, but those groups are not assigned to anything. Should I find a way to assign them?

Comment: This is likely a problem specific to the particular set-up (an option incidentally disabled that turns off deformation for instance), please upload your .blend to [pasteall.org](http://pasteall.org/blend/) and add the link to your question.

Comment: i posted it the site but i didint fin a whey to put the link to the question its posted as Bones problem

Answer (score 1):

> Should I find a way to assign them?

Yes. If the vertex group option is checked:

[image: armature modifier]

You can use the weight paint mode to change the weights of the **active vertex group** (current selection in the properties panel):
[image: weight paint]

Assign/Remove the selected vertices to/from the active vertex group in the properties panel:
[image: vertex group properties panel]

and change their weights in the viewport:
[image: viewport edit mode]